How to handle binary response in Azure logic apps correctly?
My workflow requires 2 steps

Call an external HTTP API which returns a binary file / pdf.
Convert that to a base64 string and send it to another API.

Unfortunately I'm not able interpret the binary response from the HTTP connector in a way that the pdf is not corrupt.
Response from the connector:
Binary response
Tried to use ootb base64 conversion and send it to another API via base64(body('generate_and_download_pdf'))
Is there something I miss how to handle binary response in logic apps?
Via javascript I use an array buffer, which works fine
    const response = await fetch(...);
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
    base64PDF = buffer.toString('base64');

My current workaround is to use an azure function for that part which just does the conversion in javascript as mentioned above.

Use a compose action with PDF API output in between and send the output from compose to another API might work as the logic app actions automatically tries to convert to base64


My current workaround is to use an azure function for that part which just does the conversion in JavaScript

You can run same JavaScript code which worked for you in Logic apps by using below action:


Inline scripts works when Logic app is connected with integration account.

Is there something I miss how to handle binary response in logic apps?

You can use base64 inbuilt functions:

If you want to convert to base64 or decode it you can use above inbuilt functions.
